# Characters entered from foreign users showing as?

Tags: html, character-encoding, cjk

I'm working on a site that has users from other countries. For the most part we get English text but sometimes people use special characters like Chinese symbols or the E with the accent. These symbols are displaying as "?" when shown on the site.

The site has a UTF-8 charset declaration and the SQL Server database field is Nvarchar. I did a test by going to Google translate and having it translate "Good morning" into Japanese. When I copied the resulting Kanji to my site and saved it myself it worked fine.

What could be causing this issue? I'm guessing it's because the text is being entered in a charset that is not UTF-8. Will accept-charset="UTF-8" resolve the issue? If not what can I do? Even if there is no way to fix existing bad data can I prevent this issue in the future?

Comment: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: Refering to non-english users as "foreign users", "from other countries", and non-ascci characters as "special" is rather anglo-centric.

Comment: I read that article. It didn't seem to help me. I specified in my post that I am using a charset declaration and nvarchar fields both of which are unicode. If you took something away from that page that helps please let me know. Also you might be right about the "special" characters but since the site is hosted in the US "foreign users" is an apt term and an important distinction because non-English characters entered from my computer work fine.

Comment: May be an obvious thing, but is your data base set to use UTF-8 encoding?  @leonbloy: while I might agree with your sentiment, the internet and most of its' protocols, standards, and processes are pretty much 'anglo-centric' to be honest. Foreign isn't a badword but it seems as you are injecting some type of negativity to its use.

Comment: My understanding is that in SQL server "nvarchar" = unicode. Is that not correct?

Comment: There many links in the chain "html form -> browser -> http server -> your app -> database -> your app -> your html result -> browser". You should debug to find where is the problem. To understand Unicode is essential to detect it (that "the special characters shows as '?'" says little). Can you reproduce the problem? Can you (for example) check that the entered characters are saved ok in the DB? etc

Comment: @colinross I'm not very sensitive to that. I'm from Argentina, and I even refer -informally- to spanish non-ascii chars as 'foreing' myself! But there I stand - to say "users from other countries", here, is wrong IMO.

Comment: @leonboy: yes, 'other countries' is a correct argument since the country someone is in doesn't necessarily denote the language (or charset) they use.  Back to the topic :p

Answer (score 0):

> SQL Server 7.0 and SQL Server 2000 use
>   a different Unicode encoding (UCS-2)
>   and do not recognize UTF-8 as valid
>   character data.

See the following knowledge base article for dealign with storing/retreieving utf-8 data in a MS SQL Server database: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/232580

Comment: Interesting. I'll play with it tomorrow and see if that helps.

Comment: Do you happen to know if changing my Content-Type in the website to ucs-2 should fix the issue? It doesn't seem to fix currently bad data but will it make sure that new data gets put in in the correct encoding? Or do I need to specify an accept charset on my form?

Comment: that might be a bit of buggy approach, since then you are assuming (highly unlikely) that the browser supports a non-standard content type